# HttpClientModule http.get not working

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I picked up this previous working app (Angular2) and find that it is not working (Angular4) as expected now.

Module was used (it may not matter):

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Module being used now:

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Trying to get a list of records from the backend (Node.js, Express, and MongoDB) as below.

```
    listResource(resType: string, parameters: string[]) {
    console.log("***listResource");
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/fhir+json');
    headers.append("'Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.append("Accept", "application/fhir+json");
    headers.append("USER_KEY", "QIF83Fjoe4sYxdQsah3h"); //TOUCHSTONE KEY   

    let urlString = this.baseUrl + resType + "/list"; // + queryString;
    console.log("List resource URL string: [" + urlString + "]");
    return (this.httpClient.get(urlString, { headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json()))
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error from Observable http.get call')); //...errors if any
}
```

when my component is loaded, the above listResource will be called as below.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //Get the initial 25 latest patient
    //this.progressBar = true;
    this.currentPage = 0;
    this.patientList = [];
    this.globalSvc.gPatient = [];
    console.log("***OnInit");

    this.restSvc.listResource("Patient", ["identifier=*", "family=*", "given=*"]).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Response data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
      });
  }
```

Below is the output from Chrome console. Of course, I don't get any good response. It seems to me the Chrome browser sends CORS option and the server responds correctly, then the browser doesn't send the actual GET.

[image]

If I send the REST API request from PostMan directly which doesn't have CORS, I get the expected good response from the server. Hence, it seems to me the server is ok.

Questions:

1. Any idea how to debug or fix it?
2. Will this relate to CORS on both Angular client and Node.js server?
3. The ${err.status} and ${err.error} are "undefined" in Chrome console. How can I find the actual error?

   console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);

---

**Update 1** based on Grey's suggestion on the immutable header and const.
The GET is returning data now.

[image]

Comment: 1. I do not understand why set parameters in function but not set it in your request? is this an error or you can get it without your params. 2. Try to return only error instead error.json().error. What will happen?

Comment: Hi Roma, thanks for the help. The parameters were there to construct the querystring, but I took it out just for the sake of clarity. let urlString = this.baseUrl + resType + "/list"; // + queryString;

Comment: Hi Roma, thanks again. I changed the code to throw error -    
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error '). The Chrome console now shows 'Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent]. It was 'Backend returned code undefined, body was: undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

headers.append() does not alter the headers, it returns a new Headers (because Headers is immutable).

So, instead of

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/fhir+json');
headers.append("'Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
headers.append("Accept", "application/fhir+json");
headers.append("USER_KEY", "QIF83Fjoe4sYxdQsah3h"); //TOUCHSTONE KEY
```

you need to do something like:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value")
  .append('Content-Type', 'application/fhir+json')
  .append("'Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  .append("Accept", "application/fhir+json")
  .append("USER_KEY", "QIF83Fjoe4sYxdQsah3h");
```

Oh, and that should actually be `const headers =`, rather than `let headers =`